# When was Javac StringBuilder/StringBuffer optimization introduced?

Tags: java, javac, stringbuilder, stringbuffer, jdk1.4

I know that Javac compiler is able to transform String concatenation `+` using `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer`, and I'm curious to know **starting from which version** this change was introduced?

I'm using this sample code:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String a = args[0];
      String s = "a";
      s = s + a;
      s = s + "b";
      s = s + "c";
      s = s + "d";
      s = s + "e";
      System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

So far I've tried with `javac 1.8.0_121`, `javac 1.6.0_20`, `javac 1.5.0_22` and `java 1.4.2_19`.

Here is a sample of the bytecode I see using `javap -c` from `1.4.2_19`:

```
6:  astore_2
7:  new #3; //class StringBuffer
10: dup
11: invokespecial   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuffer."<init>":()V
14: aload_2
15: invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
18: aload_1
19: invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
22: invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/lang/StringBuffer.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
```

All 4 versions seems to be using the StringBuilder/StringBuffer optimization, so I'm curious to know **starting from which Javac version** this change was introduced?

Comment: Probably since the beginning...

Comment: Java 5 if I'm not mistaken

Comment: More useful would be to know if any of them can do this for a string built with a loop.

Comment: Note that it isn't always optimized automatically by the compiler. I brought a Linux Server with Java 8 to its knees last year, by using `String#+` instead of `StringBuilder`. I wanted to build a reasonably large (about 300MB) gnuplot file. There was some logic involved, and I had to build two 150MB strings in parallel, and concatenate them at the end. With `String#+`, it took half an hour and all the memory available. With `StringBuilder`, it took just a few seconds and much less memory.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's a quote from the [language specification from version 1](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/15.doc.html#39990):

> An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate `String` object. To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the `StringBuffer` class (§20.13) or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate `String` objects that are created by evaluation of an expression.

Back at the time, they had `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder`.

Also a quote from [`StringBuffer`](http://web.mit.edu/java_v1.0.2/www/javadoc/java.lang.StringBuffer.html#_top_) of JDK1.0.2:

> This Class is a growable buffer for characters. It is mainly used to create Strings. The compiler uses it to implement the "+" operator.

Comment: Nice find, but now I have to despise my former teachers for teaching me to use the uselessly verbose syntax of `StringBuffer`/`Builder` ;-( I'll try to find some solace believing that it might not have been optimized in the early version of the OpenJDK, please nobody ruin this :p

Comment: @Aaron StringBuilder should usually be used when constructing complex strings, e.g. in loops (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java).

Comment: Oh, thanks for the precision ! While it's not the point of the question, I think it might still be interesting to add in your answer, as OP and other readers might ignore that this optimisation isn't always possible and could conclude as I erroneously did that using string concatenation everywhere is fine.

Comment: @Aaron it's not needlessly verbose. Using `StringBuilder` directly gives you control over the initial buffer size. Estimating it could save you some expensive resizing of the underlying char array.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz thanks for that other specific case where using the `StringBuilder` over string concatenation is interesting ! I however remember, maybe incorrectly, being taught to always use the `StringBuilder` over string concatenation, which would not improve performance in the general case and would impact readability and development speed. I'm not even sure teaching to systematically use `StringBuilder` over string concatenation when the string is constructed in a loop would be a good idea, that sounds like premature optimization and counter-productive for loops with few iterations

Comment: @Aaron I wouldn't call it premature optimization. If a loop does, for example, 10000 concatenations it's equally silly to use `+` as a `StringBuilder` with the default buffer of 16 characters. One case where `+` is actually faster is when concatenating static string values. In such cases the resulting string can be built at compile time.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz what I call premature optimization does not depend on how much performance you can gain, but rather on how much you need to gain. If you're developing an overnight batch which has a 2 hours span to execute, whether your terrible loop takes 15 minutes or not might not matter (memory usage might, though). Now I'd hate to make such code, but I understand the concerns of the manager who wants the code ready for yesterday or the next intern to be able to get up to speed on it quickly.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz thanks for the new interesting examples BTW, they add to my new conviction that the answer to `StringBuilder` vs string concatenation is "it depends (if it does matter)"

Comment: I wonder why Java didn't define static `String.concat` methods with various numbers of operands as well as a `String[]`?  Such things would be much more efficient than `StringBuilder` in all cases where the number of strings to be concatenated is known in advance.

Comment: No need to dive into the JLS or bytecode...just check the Javadoc for StringBuilder! It says Since: 1.5. So this answer is _not_ the best answer.

Comment: @Bludzee I believe the OP's question is about the `+` optimization in general, regardless of whether it is using `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`. Obviously the former came in Java 1.5

Answer (score 11):

I have looked up the Java Language Specification, First Edition (from 1996). Not an easy find, but [here it is](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/). The passage on concatenation optimization was there even then:

> An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate String object. To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class (§20.13) or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects that are created by evaluation of an expression.

The specification pertained to `StringBuffer` then, but `StringBuilder` (which current JLS wording refers to) might be deemed better performing because its methods are not synchronized.

This, however, does not mean that one should rely on the optimization as *always* being in place. String concatenation in loops will not get optimized, for example.

Answer (score 5):

JLS has already been given in some answers. I just want to make the point that StringBuffer (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) was there since 1.0 whereas

StringBuilder(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) came in version 1.5. Please see the `since:` section of respective javadocs.

Comment: No need to dive into the JLS or bytecode...just check the Javadoc for StringBuilder! It says `Since: 1.5`. So this answer is the best answer. (+1)

Answer (score 5):

*This does not answer the question*, but I want to merely add to the overall point that in jdk-9 this `StringBuilder::append` is *one of the permitted strategies*, but not the default one.

```
private enum Strategy {
   /**
    * Bytecode generator, calling into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder}.
    */
    BC_SB,

    /**
     * Bytecode generator, calling into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder};
     * but trying to estimate the required storage.
     */
    BC_SB_SIZED,

    /**
     * Bytecode generator, calling into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder};
     * but computing the required storage exactly.
     */
     BC_SB_SIZED_EXACT,

   /**
    * MethodHandle-based generator, that in the end calls into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder}.
    * This strategy also tries to estimate the required storage.
    */
    MH_SB_SIZED,

    /**
     * MethodHandle-based generator, that in the end calls into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder}.
     * This strategy also estimate the required storage exactly.
     */
    MH_SB_SIZED_EXACT,

    /**
     * MethodHandle-based generator, that constructs its own byte[] array from
     * the arguments. It computes the required storage exactly.
     */
     MH_INLINE_SIZED_EXACT
}
```

It's actually an `invokedynamic` bytecode for String concatenation, so it's implementation is now JRE specific, not compiler one. The default strategy btw is : `MH_INLINE_SIZED_EXACT`

Comment: Sorry but could you explain what *permitted strategies* means? Is it some runtime optimization dedicated to string concatenation?

Comment: @glee8e I think I've covered the topic a bit here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40267601/how-much-does-java-optimize-string-concatenation-with/42138460#42138460